# Retrive data from chainlink node

Tags: contract-invocation, events, chainlink, goerli, api

in APIConsumer contract on chainlink docs (Any API)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * THIS EXAMPLE USES UN-AUDITED CODE.
 * DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint256 public volume;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestVolume(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 volume);

    /**
     * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
     *
     * Goerli Testnet details:
     * Link Token: 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
     * Oracle: 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7 (Chainlink DevRel)
     * jobId: ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb
     *
     */
    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        setChainlinkOracle(0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7);
        jobId = "ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb";
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }

    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );

        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        req.add(
            "get",
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD"
        );

        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        // request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR"); // Chainlink nodes prior to 1.0.0 support this format
        req.add("path", "RAW,ETH,USD,VOLUME24HOUR"); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format

        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int256 timesAmount = 10 ** 18;
        req.addInt("times", timesAmount);

        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */
    function fulfill(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        uint256 _volume
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestVolume(_requestId, _volume);
        volume = _volume;
    }

    /**
     * Allow withdraw of Link tokens from the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
}
```

i want to call the request function from another contract and retrieve the value returned in the fulfill function in the caller contract, *my question is* : **how do i know that fulfill returned new value since we can't listen to events in solidity ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say we have Contract CallingAPIConsumer and Contract APIConsumer.

You could have a function in `CallingAPIConsumer` that APIConsumer calls when `fullfill()` is executed, let's call it `getVolumeData(uint256 _vol)`.
To do this you would also need the address of the CallingAPIConsumer contract.

So now it would look like this

`CallingAPIConsumer.triggerVolumeRequest() -> APIConsumer.requestVolumeData() [this stores the address of the destination contract]`

`APIConsumer.fullfill(uint256 _volume) -> CallingAPIConsumer.receiveVolumeData(uint256 _volume)`